# Save image taken from iPad/iPhone to sql server database base64

Tags: ios, sql-server, image

I am having trouble saving data from my iPad app to SQL server.  I think it mostly has to do with data types.  Starting from the database I have my Image field as SQL Server data type: image.  I looked for an equivalent data type in .NET and I found from this linkk: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716729.aspx that the best choice is a byte array: Byte[]

In the entity/class I am using in .NET I have the following: public class MyClass { public Byte[] Image { get; set; } } and the parameter I am using to to pass in this data looks like this:

```
SqlParameter param_image = cmd.Parameters.Add("IMAGE", SqlDbType.Image, item.Image.Length);
param_image.Value = System.Convert.FromBase64String(item.Image);
param_image.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
```

However, I am getting an error from the parameter about trying to convert from a string to a byte array.  Has anyone done this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two remarks:

- item.Image is Byte[], and not String as expected from
  FromBase64String (may be this is your error?). try:

  param_image.Value = item.Image
- you should use varbinary(max) instead of IMAGE datatype: the IMAGE data type
  is deprecated (supported but will be removed in the future)

Comment: Remus and Alain, thank you both for your help.  I did get it working using the image data type.  Since the string was already a Base64 string I was able to just assign the item.Image to my parameter's value as shown above.  I understand what you are both saying about the Image data type being deprecated, however, if you have a look at the link I provided above there is no mention of this and in fact Microsoft's site mentions that the Byte[] (.NET) should be used with IMAGE (SQL SERVER).  Can you provide to me the documentation that supports deprecation please?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx deprecated wut still working with sql2012.

Comment: Ok thanks Alain, we are using SQL Server 2005 for the foreseeable future.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use IMAGE, is a deprecated data type. Use VARBIANRY(MAX). Storing data as base64 encoded is questionable as it wastes space. On the other hand is true that it saves processing when serving the image, but that porocessing can be pushed to the HTTP server(S) and hence scaled out, while the space loss cannot be alleviated. I would favor storing unconnected binary image stream. For a full example *that utilizes streaming semantics* of upload and download media to/from SQL Server via HTTP see [Download and Upload Images from SQL Server via ASP.NET MVC](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/140713/Download-and-Upload-Images-from-SQL-Server-via-ASP). Adapting it for iOS interaction is easy, and the concept can be adapted to do even smarter things to achieve end-to-end streaming (ie. not HTTP while-file post, but individual fragments sent/received from client). The importance of using streaming semantics cannot be emphasized enough when manipulating large media type content (images, video, documents).