# Upload images to server directory

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, nsurlconnection, nsurlrequest

I need to upload some images (taken from the camera or from photo library) to the server. The images are bonded to an user e each user can have one are more group of images bonded to a post, it will be like this:

```
User1 -> Post1 -> Image1, Image2
         Post2 -> Image3
         Post3 -> Image4, Image5, Image6
```

Each user will have his directory to store his images, and the image directory will have a directory to each post.

```
Server/../User1/Images/Post1
Server/../User1/Images/Post2
...
```

how can i send this images to the server and how can i create such directories to store it (if does not exist)?

I having some ideas how to accomplish that using http requests, but what's the best approach? Send the images directly from device or send it to a webservice e it will do the hard work?

Ether way i need some highlights how to accomplish it, i've never send images to a server from iOS before.

PS.: If someone knows to how to send more then one image on the same request i'll be grateful =)

Comment: Can you post some details about the server? It helps in answering your question.

Comment: The server is just a http server where i store my webservice and resources like images. Th interaction is made by URL, so i want to pass the URL that represents the directory to store the images.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at these previous SO posts regarding uploading an image from an iOS device to a server:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5752334/how-to-save-images-in-a-server-path-folder-from-iphone-application

[iphone SDK : Upload image from iphone to a php Server send empty file ?(sample code link inside)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3985515/iphone-sdk-upload-image-from-iphone-to-a-php-server-send-empty-file-sample-c)

[how to save image to server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15247609/how-to-save-image-to-server)

[How can i upload an image to server directory directly form iOS using FTP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9647756/how-can-i-upload-an-image-to-server-directory-directly-form-ios-using-ftp)

[Upload image to server from iOS device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12004054/upload-image-to-server-from-ios-device)

[post image to server in iphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16434537/post-image-to-server-in-iphone)

[Save image taken from iPad/iPhone to sql server database base64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13186967/save-image-taken-from-ipad-iphone-to-sql-server-database-base64)